# How to fix error 502 status

Tags: java, web, jsoup

I am using Jsoup Java HTML parser to fetch images from a particular URL. But some of the images are throwing a status 502 error code and are not saved to my machine. Here is the code snapshot i have used:-

```
String url = "http://www.jabong.com";
String html = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get().html();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, url);
images = doc.select("img");

for (Element element : images) {
        String imgSrc = element.attr("abs:src");
        log.info(imgSrc);
        if (imgSrc != "") {
            saveFromUrl(imgSrc, dirPath+"/" + nameCounter + ".jpg");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error("error in sleeping");
            }
            nameCounter++;
        }
}
```

And the saveFromURL function looks like this:-

```
public static void saveFromUrl(String Url, String destinationFile) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(Url);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error in saving file from url:" + Url);
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I searched on internet about status code 502 but it says error is due to bad gateway. I don't understand this. One of the possible things i am thinking that this error may be because of I am sending get request to images in loop. May be webserver is not able handle to this much load so denying the request to the images when previous image is not sent.So I tried to put sleep after fetching every image but no luck :( 
Some advices please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full code example that works for me...

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URL;

public class DownloadImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // URLs for Images we wish to download
        String[] urls = {
                "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
                "http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png",
                "http://i.microsoft.com/global/en-us/homepage/PublishingImages/sprites/microsoft_gray.png"
                };

        for(int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            downloadFromUrl(urls[i]);
        }

    }

    /*
    Extract the file name from the URL
    */
    private static String getOutputFileName(URL url) {

        String[] urlParts = url.getPath().split("/");

        return "c:/temp/" + urlParts[urlParts.length-1];
    }

    /*
    Assumes there is no Proxy server involved.
    */
    private static void downloadFromUrl(String urlString) {

        InputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null; 

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            System.out.println("Reading..." + url);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);

            is = conn.getInputStream(); 

            String filename = getOutputFileName(url);

            fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);

            byte[] readData = new byte[1024];

            int i = is.read(readData);

            while(i != -1) {
                fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                i = is.read(readData);
            }

            System.out.println("Created file: " + filename);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Big problems if InputStream cannot be closed");
                }
            }           
            if(fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Big problems if FileOutputSream cannot be closed");
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Completed");
    }
}
```

You should see the following ouput on your console...

```
Reading...http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png
Created file: c:/temp/apple-touch-icon.png
Completed
Reading...http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png
Created file: c:/temp/logo3w.png
Completed
Reading...http://i.microsoft.com/global/en-us/homepage/PublishingImages/sprites/microsoft_gray.png
Created file: c:/temp/microsoft_gray.png
Completed
```

So that's a working example without a Proxy server involved.

**Only if you require authentication with a proxy server** here's an additional Class that you'll need based on this [Oracle technote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html)

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class ProxyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    private String userName, password;

    public ProxyAuthenticator(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

And to use this new Class you would use the following code in place of the call to openConnection() shown above

```
...
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    System.out.println("Reading..." + url);

    Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator("username", "password");

    SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("proxy.server.com", 80);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds like HTTP communication issues, so you are probably better off trying to use a library to handle the communication side of things. Take a look at [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

Some notes about your code example. You haven't used a `URLConnection` object so it's not clear what the behaviour will be in regards to the Web/Proxy servers and closing resources cleanly, etc. The HttpCommon library mentioned will help in this aspect.

There also seems to be some examples of doing what you want using [J2ME libararies](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/how-to-download-an-image-from-a-web-server.html). Not something I have used personally but may also help you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot brad. being a newbie didn't know about URLConnection object thing. It's still not clear to me what are you trying to say by closing resources cleanly..Please explain

Comment: Are you still getting a 502 error? I posted another code example without the JSoup business for you to try out. Maybe it will help identify where the issue lies.

Comment: Hey Thanks Brad, Thanks for solving the problem. Since I got this issue, I changed the relative URLS to absolute URLs using jsoup and that did solve my purpose and thanks a lot for helping me out and giving me the exact solution..Cheers \m/